# On a global analytical continuation principle

Tags: complex-analysis

I was thinking about a kind of global analytical continuation. Is the following result true? Any idea on how to prove it?
Let $g:[0,1]\times D(0,1) \longrightarrow \mathbb{C}$. Also, let $\gamma(t)$ be a closed path.
Suppose that $\forall t \in [0,1]$, $g_t=g(t,\cdot) \in \mathcal{H}(D(0,1))$.
Furthermore, asume that $\forall t_i,t_f$ such that $\|\gamma(t)-\gamma(t_i)\|<1 \forall t \in [t_i,t_f]$, then $g(t_f,0)=g(t_i,\gamma(t_f)-\gamma(t_i))$.
Does it follow that $g_0-g_1=cte$
The picture is that one is moving through the complex plane, and you are 'continuoing' a function and end up coming up where you started.

Comment: I don't know what "$cte$" means.

Comment: @GerryMyerson constant